# GCM Send Messages to Topics: TOO_MANY_TOPICS error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Previously GCM has a limit of 1 million topics subscriptions per app, which I see they have now done away with :

> Based on the publish/subscribe model, topic messaging supports
>   unlimited subscriptions per app.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

However, it appears that if a single instance of an app subscribes to too many topics, it will give you this TOO_MANY_TOPICS error.

> returns when single app instance subscribes to an excessive number of topics.

I'm trying to implement a forum on android where I plan to use GCM Topics to subscribe people to post / comment on the post on GCM Topics and when there are further updates on posts occur, my server will send notifications to subscribers through GCM.

As you can imagine, people on forums can be quite active, commenting or posting everyday.

Has anyone encountered this GCM error and can give an indication of what an excessive number of subscriptions to topics is?

I wish Google could give us an indication on what they define as an excessive number of subscriptions to topics. I also don't see anyway of me or anyone else testing this out until we generate this error ourselves so we can measure what the excessive number is.

Comment: Hi Simon, does this limit refers to an Android app installed on a single device that can be subscribed up to 1 million toipics? If so, I don't see any impact on your  service.  If only 1% of 1 million topics says something daily, your device is likely to explode, so 1 I guess 1 million subscriptions is not a good idea. Said that, now you can take a look to Firebase Cloud Messaging launched a couple of days before and check if better suits.

Comment: The 1 million topics subscription per app by Google has now fallen away