# How many topics can we make in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an app where I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging. But I have some doubts. I want to know how many topics we could make in one app instance?

In [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) it writes that

> when a single app instance subscribes to an excessive number of topics

it retrieves error ***TOO_MANY_TOPICS***.

I want to know how many topics is allowed. I know that we don't have [constraints about number of subscribers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37830098/4625829) and that is okay, but I want to know how many topics could we make in one app instance. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Kinda similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/34382077/4625829

Comment: No it isn't. That question I had posted too, and if you read carefully this post, it writes that I know that we have not constraints about number of subscribers, but it seems that constraint about number of topics really have. So that question don't help me here!

Comment: I did notice that after I commented it. Upvoted and linked a different question. Modified your post since it's misleading, you were originally specifying *in one app* instead of *in one app **instance***, which made me thought it was a duplicate of your previous post. The new post I linked is similar, though it was asked months ago, for GCM.

Comment: So, do you know how many topics is allowed? They would not post that  TOO_MANY_TOPICS. if there are no constrains...

Comment: If I did, I would've provided an answer. Haven't encountered it yet, and nothing is mentioned in the docs. Linked to the other post so that there might be someone looking over these two tags that can provide a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard limit on the number of topics an instance can subscribe to, this limit, like many other limits on FCM are in place to prevent abuse. You are unlikely to hit the limit if an instance is subscribed to less than a few thousand topics. If however this is insufficient and you are indeed hitting the subscription limit then I'd advise that you contact Firebase Support.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_and_unsubscribe_using_the), One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Some things to keep in mind about topics:

Topic messaging supports unlimited topics and subscriptions for each app.

You get too many topics error if you are subscribing for too many topics from a single app instance to check abuse.